# multiple instance can't use the same variable, variable not changing

Tags: java

I am not quite sure what is wrong with this, I am sure it has to do with the scope. Yesterday I had an issue where a field would initialize itself back to zero due to me recalling the method more than once, making a class field fixed this as it retained it's value regardless of  how many time any method is called.

Now I have the opposite problem, I need the field to reset because another object needs to use it(is this possible/bad practice?)

Here is the code:

```
public class TestDigitalCamera {

    static String brand;
    static double megaPixels;
    static double price;

    //create 2 camera instances with the values of the variables tied to the arguments.
    static DigitalCamera camera = new DigitalCamera(brand, megaPixels);
    static DigitalCamera camera2 = new DigitalCamera(brand, megaPixels);


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //no idea what this technique is called, need to look back but I know what it does
        //I could use a for loop and reuse the same object over and over(would that even work anyway?) but the task says
        //that i require 4 instances, ofc I am just working with 2 atm for simplicity
        camera = getInformation(camera);
        displayInfo();
        camera2 = getInformation(camera2);
        displayInfo();


    }

    //it basically runs this for the camera instance...right? lol
    public static DigitalCamera getInformation(DigitalCamera dc){
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        //self explanatory
        System.out.println("Enter brand: ");
        brand = userInput.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Mega Pixels: ");
        megaPixels = userInput.nextDouble();

        //I have another class setup with getters/setters for this, which get used in the next method
        dc.setBrand(brand);
        dc.setMegaPixels(megaPixels);
        return dc;      

    }

    public static void displayInfo(){

        //users the getters to pull the values
        //the price is calculated using an if statement
        System.out.println("Brand: " + camera.getBrand() + "\n"
                + "Megapixels : " + camera.getMegaPixels() + "\n"
                        + "Price : $" + camera.getPrice() + "\n");
    }

}
```

Is this due to the scope? the variable is use-able for any and all objects but it may only be used for 1? What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: Are you aware that displayInfo always uses camera, so it never uses camera2?

Comment: OMG...I feel like such a tool lol. What would be the best way to get it to output both without having to duplicate the code?

Comment: make displayInfo take an argument: displayInfo(DigitalCamera camera)

Comment: Yep I presumed that, thanks for clearing that up

Comment: Any reason why you can't make `displayInfo` an instance method of the `DigitalCamera` class? That way, you could simply do `camera.displayInfo()` and `camera2.displayInfo()`.

Comment: No reason at all, I am still learning so all these different ways come and go from my mind as I go through my book

Answer (score 2):

You have this code:

```
camera = getInformation(camera);
displayInfo();
camera2 = getInformation(camera2);
displayInfo();
```

Here your method `displayInfo()` is not really taking any argument and printing information from `camera` object both the times it is called. Even though you are getting reference of `camera2` object in second call of `getInformation` you aren't really printing it.

You can declare `displayInfo` like this:

```
public static void displayInfo(DigitalCamera camera) {
    //users the getters to pull the values
    //the price is calculated using an if statement
    System.out.println("Brand: " + camera.getBrand() + "\n"
         + "Megapixels : " + camera.getMegaPixels() + "\n"
         + "Price : $" + camera.getPrice() + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor your code like this :

```
public static void displayInfo(DigitalCamera camera){

    //users the getters to pull the values
    //the price is calculated using an if statement
    System.out.println("Brand: " + camera.getBrand() + "\n"
            + "Megapixels : " + camera.getMegaPixels() + "\n"
                    + "Price : $" + camera.getPrice() + "\n");
}
```

And then in the `main` method :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    camera = getInformation(camera);
    displayInfo(camera);
    camera2 = getInformation(camera2);
    displayInfo(camera2);


}
```

If you declare your two `DigitalCamera` instances  in the `main` method like this

```
DigitalCamera camera = getInformation(camera);
```

then there is no need for separate static variables.

I would stronlgy recommend you to read the part about Class and Instance members in the Java Tutorial : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: I will read that, I have been mainly learning from my book. Which does in fact send you to the java documentation every so often to get you used to referring to it

Comment: Very good. But I presume your book refers to the Java API documentation, which is not be confused withe the Java Tutorials.

Comment: tbh looking at my code, seems very stupid. I have the variable names tied to the arguments, which actually do nothing since I am using a setter...I guess I can straight up just do a standard method asking for user input to initialize the variables

Answer (score 0):

I would write your class this way

public class TestDigitalCamera {

```
public static test_display(){
    DigitalCamera camera = getCamera();
    System.out.println("Brand: " + camera.getBrand() + "\n"
            + "Megapixels : " + camera.getMegaPixels() + "\n"
            + "Price : $" + camera.getPrice() + "\n");

}

public static getCamera(){
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    //self explanatory
    System.out.println("Enter brand: ");
    brand = userInput.next();
    System.out.println("Enter Mega Pixels: ");
    megaPixels = userInput.nextDouble();

    //I have another class setup with getters/setters for this, which get used in the next method
    DigitalCamera dc = new DigitalCamera();
    dc.setBrand(brand);
    dc.setMegaPixels(megaPixels);
    return dc;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    test_displainfo();
}
```

}

Comment: Interesting, what are your reasons behind doing it this way? Is it so you can recall the method whenever you want and always have a new camera object? rather than creating xxx amount of instances?

Comment: Yes you can just call this method whenever you want to create new Camera object. And also instance variables you created belongs to camera object so you should not be creating as instance variables for TestCamera class. If you want to make it better, get rid of Scanner class and create json/xml/properties file list of camera properties you want to display and read that file and create camera object for each property.